# Xamarin forms app crashing on Android after launching (works on first install)

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin, httpwebrequest

Xamarin forms app crashing on Android after launching (works on first install).

First time I launch I ask for a login and save the credentials. On the second launch I use those credentials, automatically login and then launch the main form. If I change my code to ask for the login every time (the App.cs creates a form instead when it crashes I fire the login object and when it returns I create the next form on the UI thread in the call back in the App.cs)

It is crashing outside of my code. I don't know how to see what is causing the crash (it doesn't throw the exception back to my C# code).

It fails when I am making a webrequest and usually when I am adding the cookie to the header

Fails usually in the third and sometimes the fourth line here

```
var cc = new CookieContainer();
Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("MyCookie", sessionToken);                  
cc.Add(webRequest.RequestUri, myCookie);
webRequest.CookieContainer = cc;
```

This code has a callback to my main form and is fired in an event if it matters.

I did look at the Android log and don't see anything obvious to me. I will copy it below.

Any ideas? I am not sure how to debug this.

Log code for when it fails

```
Android application is debugging.
This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.

Android application is debugging.
This debug engine does not support exception conditions. The condition(s) will be ignored.
07-22 12:59:20.912 I/art     ( 3369): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-22 12:59:20.913 W/art     ( 3369): Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-22 12:59:21.015 W/monodroid( 3369): Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/com.noregon.tripVision/files/.__override__`
07-22 12:59:21.015 W/monodroid( 3369): Using override path: /data/user/0/com.noregon.tripVision/files/.__override__
07-22 12:59:21.016 W/monodroid( 3369): Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/com.noregon.tripVision/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
07-22 12:59:21.016 W/monodroid( 3369): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.noregon.tripVision/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
07-22 12:59:21.016 W/monodroid( 3369): Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/com.noregon.tripVision-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-2.0.so
07-22 12:59:21.017 W/monodroid-debug( 3369): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8873,server=y,embedding=1
07-22 12:59:21.049 W/monodroid-debug( 3369): Accepted stdout connection: 34
07-22 12:59:21.868 D/Mono    ( 3369): Image addref mscorlib[0x9abdc000] -> mscorlib.dll[0xa620c300]: 2
07-22 12:59:21.868 D/Mono    ( 3369): Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (mscorlib.dll)
07-22 12:59:21.868 D/Mono    ( 3369): AOT: image 'mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.noregon.tripVision-1/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
07-22 12:59:21.869 D/Mono    ( 3369): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/mscorlib.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.noregon.tripVision-1/lib/x86/libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" not found
07-22 12:59:21.870 D/Mono    ( 3369): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.

.........................................
07-22 12:59:46.085 D/Mono    ( 3369): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform[0x9abdd620] -> Xamarin.Forms.Core[0x9abdd560]: 5
07-22 12:59:48.683 D/Mono    ( 3369): Assembly Ref addref System.Collections[0x9abddec0] -> System.Core[0x9abde280]: 9
07-22 12:59:57.196 D/Mono    ( 3369): DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
07-22 12:59:57.196 D/Mono    ( 3369): DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
07-22 12:59:57.196 D/Mono    ( 3369): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
07-22 12:59:57.196 D/Mono    ( 3369): Searching for 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
07-22 12:59:57.196 D/Mono    ( 3369): Probing 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
07-22 12:59:57.196 D/Mono    ( 3369): Found as 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
07-22 12:59:57.197 D/Mono    ( 3369): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
07-22 12:59:57.197 D/Mono    ( 3369): Searching for 'monodroid_free'.
07-22 12:59:57.197 D/Mono    ( 3369): Probing 'monodroid_free'.
07-22 12:59:57.197 D/Mono    ( 3369): Found as 'monodroid_free'.
07-22 12:59:57.204 W/gralloc_ranchu( 3369): Gralloc pipe failed
07-22 12:59:57.205 D/        ( 3369): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x885dbc80, tid 3369
07-22 12:59:57.224 D/Mono    ( 3369): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
07-22 12:59:57.224 D/Mono    ( 3369): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_int_method_a'.
07-22 12:59:57.224 D/Mono    ( 3369): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_int_method_a'.
07-22 12:59:57.224 D/Mono    ( 3369): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_int_method_a'.
07-22 12:59:57.244 D/        ( 3369): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x885dbf40, tid 3402
07-22 12:59:57.260 I/OpenGLRenderer( 3369): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-22 12:59:57.260 D/OpenGLRenderer( 3369): Swap behavior 1
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
07-22 13:00:16.843 D/Mono    ( 3369): [0x8627f920] worker finishing
The thread 'Unknown' (0x7) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #6
07-22 13:00:20.503 D/Mono    ( 3369): [0x8647d920] worker finishing
The thread 'Unknown' (0x6) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: For the "missing libaot-mscorlib.dll.so" issue, did you try to uncheck `Use Fast Deployment` of your android project?

Comment: I don't see an option for "Use Fast Deployement". Is that a VS 2013 option? I am running VS 2017   EDIT: Never mind I see that under "Use Shared Runtime" and neither is selected

Comment: I tried several different build options now (link SDK, with and without Progaurd) and still get the same crash.

Comment: Maybe the reason is that you didn't have all `.so` file for all Architectures. You could modify your Android project setting : `Properties` -> `Android Options` -> `Advanced` -> `Supported architectures` -> Select `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` only.

Comment: Do you have libs folder that put `.so` file in different architectures folder?